# Where to invoke ExecutorService.shutdown() in web application

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, application-shutdown, servlet-container

I wonder what is correct place to shutdown `ExecutorService` in a web application?

According to docs `ExecutorService` should be shutdown, but what is correct place in the code to do that in a web application?

**UPDATE:** Sorry for unclarity. Let's consider under Java EE a web based application with MVC (for instance Spring MVC if that matter). It has Controllers->Facades->Services. It doesnt have EJBs.

Comment: Please clarify/focus your question, it's too broad: Servlets only or EJBs as well? From an AsyncServlet, @Asynchronous and EJB MDB point of view I am tempted to say there is no need to search for such a location (and leave it to the container to manage threads).

Answer (score 0):

"Java EE" covers a wide array of technologies. If you're talking about a servlet, the container will call `destroy()` when it's being shut down, and you could close out your `ExecutorService` there. If the service is owned by a managed bean, you could use `@PreDestroy` to mark a method to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a hook using a `ServletContextListener`:

```
@WebListener
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {
        log.info("Hello");
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e) {
        log.info("Bye");

        // Do cleanups here
    }
}
```